# Change the product price upon changing the quantity of Ecommerce Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increase or decrease the item from input field. On doing so I also want to update the product price. Everything is fine in console, but I am unable to access and update the price in html. How can I do it? Thank You.

I want to add the new price to:

```html
<td class="total-price">
  <p class="price">
    $200
  </p>
</td>
```

Thank You!

```js
/* handling the quantity increase decrease */
$('.js-number').on('click', function() {
  var currentQty = $(this).val()
  var discountedPrice = $(this).attr('data')

  console.log(discountedPrice)

  $('.js-number').change(function() {
    var updatedQty = $(this).val()
    var updatedPrice = discountedPrice * updatedQty
    $(this).val(updatedQty)

    console.log(updatedQty)
    console.log(updatedPrice)
    $(this).closest(".total-price > .price").html(updatedPrice)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="bcart-quantity single-product-detail">
      <div class="single-product-info">
        <div class="e-quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="999" 
            name="quantity" value="2" title="Qty" class="qty input-text js-number" 
            size="4" data="200">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="total-price">
      <p class="price">
        $200
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to nest event handlers. You're creating a new change function every time your click function runs. Also, there _is_ no change function _until_ the click function runs once.

Comment: Actually this UI is For cart page of ecommerce, where once the person goes for checkout he vist his cat to see the amont and quantity. The input field is the quantity and whenever customer change the value in it the price associated with it should be change as well which is in the second ```<td>```. ```$(this).closest("tr").find('.price').text('$' + updatedPrice)``` This line of code worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Put that in your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared for you this script that should work. The problem was the `closest`

According to JQuery documentation `closest` works like this:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
> selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
> ancestors in the DOM tree.

So change it with:

```
/* handeling the quantity increase decrease */
$('.js-number').on('click', function() {
  var currentQty = $(this).val()
  var discountedPrice = $(this).attr('data')
  var updatedQty = $(this).val()
  var updatedPrice = discountedPrice * updatedQty
  $(this).val(updatedQty)
  $(this).closest("tr").find('.price').text('$' + updatedPrice)
})
```